# new home single topic MathSciNet

Tags: discussion

Does anyone know anything about the new offer from the AMS of getting home access to single topics in MathSciNet?

http://www.ams.org/publications/math-reviews/math-reviews

damn it, now i can't find the link. It came with the dues notification, I keep meaning to call them.

This must be it:

http://www.ams.org/bookstore/emrsections

Anyway, if it is just a bunch of pdf's of reviews, that is not so great. If it allows searching within the topic, including past reviews,  (i would subscribe to 11, Number Theory), that's pretty good. The point is, I'm living in the past.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EsCyC1dZiN8

Either that or i'm running with the pack. And never looking back, so that's probably not me...

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ynFqrrZukk

Comment: Do you think MathOverflow meta is really the right place for this question?

Comment: @StefanKohl, I don't know, from time to time i have questions about the community life of mathematicians rather than about mathematics or about MO Main. I try them here, usually there is little total complaint.

Comment: I see only one other question of yours here which is unrelated to MO -- and that was indeed received well: http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/405/quick-or-easy-methods-to-post-math-or-diagrams-on-chat

Comment: @StefanKohl, it appears I also started 17 "discussions" at what is now called tea.mathoverflow, anyway my little summary is at http://tea.mathoverflow.net/account/208/ and "discussions" are at http://tea.mathoverflow.net/discussions/  Note that most difficult aspects of policy and behavior for MO were fought over there.

Comment: Ah, I still miss tea. Carry on.

Comment: @Scott: No reason not to drink tea, or post on tea while drinking tea, or post on tea while drinking a single malt old enough to vote... Or whatever. The point is, that we can still use tea. It would be great, however, if there was a small script with a notification of the timestamp on the last post there.

Answer (score 4):

Alright, I just called the A.M.S. I had it roughly correct. This new service is a monthly posting of all reviews in a sections, available as downloads, I guess you have a password. But no searching reviews prior to the time you signed up, and probably no keyword searching anyway.

If you are current or emeritus at an intitution that subscribes in full to MathSciNet, and they are willing to fill out a little form that says you are really affiliated, you can get the whole ball of wax on a home computer or tablet for $25.00 a year.

Comment: You probably already know this, but in any case: The AMS now also offers mobile access. If you have a laptop (or tablet or something else which you can carry) and access to a place which subscribes to mathscinet, you take your laptop this place, go to mathscinet, klick on "mobile access" in the top right corner, and follow the instructions. This installs a cookie, and you will be able to access mathscinet with your laptop from home (or anywhere) for 90 days.

Comment: @Lars, thanks..

Comment: It's also not _too_ hard to set up a VPN (virtual private network), where you bounce your web traffic off your institution's computers before sending it on to the AMS.  This also works for journal access.

Comment: @Lars: I did not know that. That is actually rather convenient.